# Is there a way to eliminate all duplicates from a collection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection where the objects have a structure similar to

```py
{'_id': ObjectId('5e691cb9e73282f624362221'), 
 'created_at': 'Tue Mar 10 09:23:54 +0000 2020', 
 'id': 1237308186757120001, 
 'id_str': '1237308186757120001', 
 'full_text': 'See you in July'}
```

I am struggling to only keep object which have a unique full text. Using distinct only gives me a list of the distinct full text field values where as I want to only conserve object in the collection with unique full texts.

Answer (score 0):

There is, the code should look like this:

```
dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "a": 5, "d": 4, "e": 5, "c": 8}

#New clean dictionary
unique = {}
#Go through the original dictionary's items
for key, value in dict.items():
    if(key in unique.keys()):
    #If the key already exists in the new dictionary
        continue
    else:
    #Otherwise
        unique[key] = value

print(unique)
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

### MongoDB way

We perform MongoDB aggregation where we group records by `full_text`, filter unique documents only and insert them into collection. (in the shell)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$full_text",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $eq: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$data",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "tmp"
  }
])
```

When you run this query, it will create new collection with unique `full_text` values. You can drop old collection and rename this one.

You may also put your collection name into `$out` operator like this `{$out:"collection"}`, but **there is no going back**.

### Python way

We perform MongoDB aggregation grouping by `full_text` field, filter duplicate documents and create single array with all `_id` to be removed. Once MongoDB returns results, we execute `remove` command for duplicate documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$full_text",
      data: {
        $push: "$_id"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sHRMWXroRwL)

### Pseudocode

```
data = list(collection.aggregate(...))
if len(data) > 0:
    colleciton.remove({'_id':{'$in':data[0]["data"]}})
```

Comment: I don't understand the "Python Way" example. It's not valid aggregation for pymongo--what is it?